# Pandas dataframe with hierarchical index of varying depths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas has a nice and featureful mechanism for dataframes with hierarchical indexes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html, but it's mainly aimed at the case where the depth of the hierarchy is constant. Is there a standard, perhaps less featureful way to have a dataframe with a hierarchical index with varying depth?

I don't really need the partial indexing and grouping and stacking/unstacking features of a MultiIndex, a dataframe where the columns are indexed by raw tuples would suit my needs.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ("a",):   [1],
    ("b",):   [2],
    ("x", 1): [3],
    ("x", 2): [4]
})
```

However, pandas's default MultiIndex is a bit overeager for my purposes in this situation. For example, it makes the "true" index of the first column be `("a", nan)`. Then `df[("a",)]` returns all columns whose index starts with `("a",)` including, e.g. a column like `("a", 1)` if it is present.

One option would be to do something like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a":      [1],
    "b":      [2],
    ("x", 1): [3],
    ("x", 2): [4]
})
```

which creates a dataframe indexed by a mix of strings and tuples, but this appears to be unsupported.

Comment: `which creates a dataframe indexed by a mix of strings and tuples, but this appears to be unsupported` - what is not supported? Selecting? Creating df ? I think main problem is it is possible create, but pandas function are confused - obviously are buggy with this non statndard hybrid index.

Comment: Creating the dataframe works. Selecting is sometimes broken: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23610.